# Catch errors during Node stream and continue processing stream

Tags: node.js, typescript, node-streams

I have a ETL pipeline that streams an HTTP body from a S3 GetObjectCommand request.

```
    await pipeline(
      await new S3Extractor(s3Path).extract(),
      await new CsvParser().parse(),
      await new CsvTransformer().transform(),
      (await new DbLoader().load())
        .on('data', (result) => {
          log.info('Successfully loaded record...');          
          ++rowCount;
        })
    );
```

Is it possible to catch exceptions that may occur (during `CsvParser.parse()`, for one example), discard the chunk that causes the exception, and continue processing the next chunk of the stream?

```
    await pipeline(
      await new S3Extractor(s3Path).extract(),
      await new CsvParser().parse().on('error', (e) => console.log('This chunk failed, discard and move onto next chunk in stream')),
      await new CsvTransformer().transform(),
      (await new DbLoader().load())
        .on('data', (result) => {
          log.info('Successfully loaded record...');          
          ++rowCount;
        })
    );
```

Given that the stream closes after the `error` event (per Node documentation) it doesn't seem like this is supported. The only alternative I can see is catching the exceptions within my classes to prevent the exception from bubbling up to fire a `error` event, and manually dealing with discarding the chunk.

Comment: What library/module is `CsvParser.parse()` from?

Answer (score 0):

I think the best approach to this is to create your own transform stream and insert it in place of CsvParser().parse().

Within your custom transform stream you can try-catch the buffer chunks (or use any other filtering logic) and instead of returning an error, just exclude them from the callback.

For debugging purposes, I would first create a new custom transform stream and insert it before CsvParser().parse() to filter out and log the chunks giving errors.

Once happy that the filtering is working as required, I would implement the actual parsing within the custom transform stream and exclude CsvParser().parse() completely, as you may effectively be parsing the buffer chunks twice - once with a try-catch and then again with CsvParser().parse().

[A simple Node transform stream with the new Node 10 pipeline() function](https://ar.al/2018/12/20/a-simple-node-transform-stream-with-the-new-node-10-pipeline-function/)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, is possible.

In javacript you have 2 different syntaxes to handle promises:

- async/await
- .then()/.catch()

The second approach will return a promise after the method, so you can chain different .then() and .catch(), but still returns a promise.

```js
await new CsvParser().load()
// Successful Promise    
                  
await new CsvParser().load().then(x => ({status: 'OK'}))               
// Successful Promise that returns {status: 'OK'}

await new CsvParser().load().catch(e => ({status: 'KO', error: e})) 
// Successful Promise that returns {status: 'KO', error: {title: 'bla bla' }}
```

You can combine the two syntax in order to bring your code as clean as possible: in your case you can easily log in that whay

```js
   await pipeline(
      await new S3Extractor(s3Path).extract(),
      await new CsvParser().parse().catch(e => console.log('This chunk failed, discard and move onto next chunk in stream')),
      await new CsvTransformer().transform(),
      (await new DbLoader().load())
        .on('data', (result) => {
          log.info('Successfully loaded record...');          
          ++rowCount;
        })
    );
```

This is not the end!
If your library is returning `Promise<void>` is just working, but if your `CsvParser().parse()` is returning an object, in the catch clause you need to return something that respect pipeline assumptions in order to not break it.

```js
await new CsvParser().parse().catch(e => {
  console.log(This chunk failed, discard and move onto next chunk in stream');
  return []; // equivalent to Promise.Resolve([])
})
```

In other words catch error implies a successful promise and return object will be passed as argument to the awaiter caller.